# How to customize pagination to display all paginated page number from page 1 to last page number(suppose page number 50) without dots(...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, antd

In general pagination component shows pagination index(page numbers) separated by dots if there is more page number like in this image.

[image: This image shows pages separated by dots]

But I want to display all page numbers without dots like:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is impossible, the only thing you can do is control the number of items on the page 3 or 5 using the `showLessItems` parameter.
To display all pages numbers you need to create your own pagination component.
This is relevant for `antd` version `4.17.0` and below